# pandas resample documentation

Tags: python, documentation, pandas

So I completely understand how to use [resample](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=dataframe%20resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample), but the documentation does not do a good job explaining the options.

So most options in the `resample` function are pretty straight forward except for these two:

- rule : the offset string or object representing target conversion
- how : string, method for down- or re-sampling, default to ‘mean’

So from looking at as many examples as I found online I can see for rule you can do `'D'` for day, `'xMin'` for minutes, `'xL'` for milliseconds, but that is all I could find.

for how I have seen the following: `'first'`, `np.max`, `'last'`, `'mean'`, and `'n1n2n3n4...nx'` where nx is the first letter of each column index.

So is there somewhere in the documentation that I am missing that displays every option for `pandas.resample`'s rule and how inputs? If yes, where because I could not find it. If no, **what are all the options for them?**

Comment: For Google's wanderers, for resampling using `how='last'` and `how='first'`: don't forget to add `closed='left', label='left'`. [link](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1998)

Comment: @NasserAl-Wohaibi I am fairly confident your comment above is an indication that these options can help fully answer the following question. Have you encountered this problem before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247301/causal-resampling-values-within-time-window-until-now

Comment: how='last' is deprecated now in favor of `resample(...).last()`

Answer (score 397, accepted):

```
B         business day frequency
C         custom business day frequency (experimental)
D         calendar day frequency
W         weekly frequency
M         month end frequency
SM        semi-month end frequency (15th and end of month)
BM        business month end frequency
CBM       custom business month end frequency
MS        month start frequency
SMS       semi-month start frequency (1st and 15th)
BMS       business month start frequency
CBMS      custom business month start frequency
Q         quarter end frequency
BQ        business quarter endfrequency
QS        quarter start frequency
BQS       business quarter start frequency
A         year end frequency
BA, BY    business year end frequency
AS, YS    year start frequency
BAS, BYS  business year start frequency
BH        business hour frequency
H         hourly frequency
T, min    minutely frequency
S         secondly frequency
L, ms     milliseconds
U, us     microseconds
N         nanoseconds
```

See the [timeseries documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html). It includes a list of [offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) (and ['anchored' offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets)), and a section about [resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling).

Note that there isn't a list of all the different `how` options, because it can be any NumPy array function and any function that is available via [groupby dispatching](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-dispatch) can be passed to `how` by name.

Comment: " ... because it can be any NumPy array function and..." - yeah, I read that in the docs, but is there any documentation anywhere explaining what exactly this function is supposed to do and what it's got to do with the resampling...? I feel pretty lost here.

Comment: This should be linked to in all relevant documentation areas, like resample.  Here is the link to the abbreviations: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Comment: Added a pull request to improve the docs https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/30252

Comment: @wordsforthewise +∞ for you.  I also sometimes wonder if anyone knows that ISO8601 has a way to represent [durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

Answer (score 69):

There's more to it than this, but you're probably looking for this list:

```
B   business day frequency
C   custom business day frequency (experimental)
D   calendar day frequency
W   weekly frequency
M   month end frequency
BM  business month end frequency
MS  month start frequency
BMS business month start frequency
Q   quarter end frequency
BQ  business quarter endfrequency
QS  quarter start frequency
BQS business quarter start frequency
A   year end frequency
BA  business year end frequency
AS  year start frequency
BAS business year start frequency
H   hourly frequency
T   minutely frequency
S   secondly frequency
L   milliseconds
U   microseconds
```

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Comment: Why isn't there the 'Min' (like the '5Min' used in the documentation)?

Comment: @zyuang, only short formats are displayed here : "ms" is also absent from the list for instance

Comment: It looks like the updated the documentation. Now it shows the "min" `T, min minutely | frequency`, and also the "ms" `L, ms | milliseconds`

Answer (score 0):

If you not sure what you will get, use this function:

```py
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
print(to_offset("7D")) # <7 * Days>
print(to_offset("W")) # <Week: weekday=6>
print(to_offset("M")) # <MonthEnd>
print(to_offset("m")) # <MonthEnd>
print(to_offset("min")) # <Minute>
```

for example, **uppercase and lowercase are the same** (not like the usual M=Month and m=minute)

## Be aware

that therefore this is not the same and gives you different results:

```py
s.resample("7d").mean()
s.resample("W").mean() # is not the same!
```

The reason you can see a [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#basics): *"Warning: The default values for label and closed is ‘left’ for all frequency offsets except for ‘M’, ‘A’, ‘Q’, ‘BM’, ‘BA’, ‘BQ’, and ‘W’ which all have a default of ‘right’."*