# pandas or numpy to mean the sum of three months. Return as list

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
Date
2013-11-30    30
2013-12-31    40
2014-01-31    50
2014-02-28    10
2014-03-31    20
2014-04-30    30
2014-05-31    80
2014-06-30    90
2014-07-31    10

df = pandas.Dataframe()
```

Lets say I have a `Dataframe` as above. How can I make a mean of the months for every third month. And return it as a list.

```
lst[0] = (30 + 40 + 50)/3
lst[1] = (10 + 20 + 30)/3
lst[2] = (90 + 90 + 10)/3
```

Are there any smart ways of achieving this with `pandas` or `numpy`, as I'd like to keep the amount of days to the month, in case the `dataframe` could consist of days instead.

Comment: If there's exactly one entry per month and there's exactly `multiple of 3` entries, you could simply reshape the data into `2D`  array with `3` cols and perform `mean` across the second axis : `data.reshape(-1,3).mean(axis=1)`.

Comment: do you want to group by quarter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure **Date** is your index

Than you can perform a resample:

```
df_resampled = df.resample('90D').mean()
```

df_resampled will look like:

```
Date    
2013-11-30  40
2014-02-28  20
2014-05-29  60
```

Then you can access it with

```
d.iloc[i].values[0]
```

where **i** is your index

### Note:

**90D** means to resample for 90 days, for other values you can check this link

[pandas resample documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001389/pandas-resample-documentation)

Comment: I went with df_r = df.resample('3MS').mean(). Thanks for pointing out resampling, great help

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
In [21]: df.groupby(df.index // 3)['val'].sum().tolist()
Out[21]: [120, 60, 180]
```

if you want to group by quarter:

```
In [24]: df.groupby(df.Date.dt.quarter)['val'].sum()
Out[24]:
Date
1     80
2    200
3     10
4     70
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Data:

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
        Date  val
0 2013-11-30   30
1 2013-12-31   40
2 2014-01-31   50
3 2014-02-28   10
4 2014-03-31   20
5 2014-04-30   30
6 2014-05-31   80
7 2014-06-30   90
8 2014-07-31   10
```

Explanation:

```
In [25]: df.index // 3
Out[25]: Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype='int64')
```