# How to resample a time series per decades in python

Tags: python, time-series, resampling

How do I resample a time series per decades?

It does not like this one:

```
df.resample('10Y')
```

Comment: I suppose this is pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas resample documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001389/pandas-resample-documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letter `Y` is not the correct [offset alias](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) for year. Try:

```
df.resample('10A')
```

Answer (score 0):

df.resample('10AS')

To get the data from 01-01-1900

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.