# Resample a dataframe with a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to resample a dataframe in pandas. 
I receive in input a .csv like this (the list in Data column are in form of strings): `

```
Name,Timestamp,Data
A1,5.26,"[1.0,1.2,1.9]"
A1,5.28,"[1.8,2.1,3.9]"
A1,5.30,"[1.2,1.4,0.9]"
A1,5.32,"[...]"
...
A2,5.26,"[...]"
A2,5.28,"[...]"
A2,5.30,"[...]"
A2,5.32,"[...]"
...
A3,5.26,"[...]"
A3,5.28,"[...]"
A3,5.30,"[...]"
A3,5.32,"[...]"`
```

Datas are recorded at 50hz (so every 20ms). I want to resample 25hz (so every 40ms).

I converted the Data column from string to an actual list with

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

and the Timestamp into seconds with:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')
```

I know that I've to use the `.resample()` function so I tried with

```
df.groupby('Name').resample("40L", on='Timestamp')
```

and it doesn't give me errors but it seems it doesn't resample at all in fact I've the same number of rows with same datas and just the Timestamp column converted into Datetime (and if I add a `.mean()` after the end of resample function it gives me the error `No numeric types to aggregate`).

I want the my table after the resample looks like:

```
Name Timestamp  Data
A1    5.26     [...]
A1    5.30     [...]
...
A2    5.26     [...]
A2    5.30     [...]
...
A3    5.26     [...]
A3    5.30     [...]
```

What should I do?

Comment: do you want to resample as `mean` or just to extract those records at `5.26, 5.30...`? turning your `Data` into different columns allows you to `resample().mean()`.

Comment: Mh.. are you able to provide me both solutions? It would be very helpful. Tho i can't extract those records because i've other dataframe but with differente frequencies (e.g. from 80 to 50hz or from 200 to 50hz) so i need a more generale solution with .resample or something similar 
(Sorry for repost, message was cut and i just noticed)

Comment: please provide a little more data, e.g. other groups as well. Is the `Data` column text?

Comment: I've only these 3 columns. For every name `A1,A2,A3..` the timestamp goes from 5.26 to 40.00 + (always with almost exactly frequency of 0.2). In the .csv the `Data` column is a string 
(e.g. first row of the csv is
`A1,5.26,"[1.9549347, -9.73276, -0.36118067060405273]"` ) so in python i converted it into actual numbers by `df['Data'] = df['Data'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`
Do you need some other infos? Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is to convert the data part into actual numeric data. `ast.literal_eval` doesn't cut it because you cannot perform arithmetic operations on `list`. Here's what I would do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your.csv')
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')

df = df.join(df['Data'].str[1:-1]
                       .str.split(',', expand=True)
                       .astype(float)
            )

# resample
df.groupby('Name').resample('40L', on='Timestamp').mean()
```

After that, your `df` would be something like:

```
                                0     1    2
Name Timestamp                              
A1   1970-01-01 00:00:05.240  1.0  1.20  1.9
     1970-01-01 00:00:05.280  1.5  1.75  2.4
     1970-01-01 00:00:05.320  1.4  1.65  2.9
     1970-01-01 00:00:05.360  1.5  1.75  2.4
     1970-01-01 00:00:05.400  1.2  1.40  0.9
A2   1970-01-01 00:00:05.240  1.0  1.20  1.9
     1970-01-01 00:00:05.280  1.5  1.75  2.4
     1970-01-01 00:00:05.320  1.4  1.65  2.9
     1970-01-01 00:00:05.360  1.5  1.75  2.4
     1970-01-01 00:00:05.400  1.2  1.40  0.9
```

Comment: The code give me this error:
`pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 5, saw 3`

The problem seems to be: `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')`

Comment: Now it gives me no errors but is seems is still not resampling.
This is my .csv before executing the code:
`Name,Timestamp,Data
A1,5.26,"[1.1,1.2,1.3]"
A1,5.28,"[1.2,0.4,1.9]"
A1,5.30,"[1.1,0.4,1.8]"
A1,5.32,"[1.0,0.9,0.4]"
A2,5.26,"[1.1,0.7,0.5]"
A2,5.28,"[1.9,2.9,3.9]"
A2,5.30,"[1.4,3.2,3.1]"
A2,5.32,"[1.1,3.1,2.2]"
A3,5.26,"[1.2,3.1,2.1]"
A3,5.28,"[1.1,3.1,2.2]"
A3,5.30,"[1.2,3.0,3.0]"
A3,5.32,"[1.1,1.9,2.0]" `
(I put in next message the .csv after executing the code)

Comment: And this is my .csv after executing the code:
`Name,Timestamp,Data,0,1,2
A1,1970-01-01 00:00:05.260,"[1.1,1.2,1.3]",1.1,1.2,1.3
A1,1970-01-01 00:00:05.280,"[1.2,0.4,1.9]",1.2,0.4,1.9
A1,1970-01-01 00:00:05.300,"[1.1,0.4,1.8]",1.1,0.4,1.8
A1,1970-01-01 00:00:05.320,"[1.0,0.9,0.4]",1.0,0.9,0.4
A2,1970-01-01 00:00:05.260,"[1.1,0.7,0.5]",1.1,0.7,0.5
A2,1970-01-01 00:00:05.280,"[1.9,2.9,3.9]",1.9,2.9,3.9
A2,1970-01-01 00:00:05.300,"[1.4,3.2,3.1]",1.4,3.2,3.1
.... `
(count copy the whole .csv, too long for a comment, also i can't start a new line for a better looking table in comments)

Comment: try `df.groupby('Name').resample('40L', on='Timestamp').mean().to_csv('new.csv')`?

Comment: Wow, i don't understand why (we are just saving it in a new .csv instead of overwriting the existing one, right?) but in this way it works! Thank you! 
One last thing, now how can i put again the 3 numbers in a list returning to the "Data" column to keep the same format of the .csv that i receive in input?

Comment: It’s because the `df.groupby()...` command creates a new dataframe, which then you can chain it with `to_csv` to write out.

Comment: Oh well, it's interesting! Thank you so much for all the help( and ignore my last question, i already did it)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to interpolate the samples and only keep every other one it is enough for you to drop every other row, keeping the first:

```
df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[::2])
```

Any interpolation of the samples would require some information on the algorithm of aggregation that you would like to employ as Quang Hoang suggested in the comment.

---

### Resampling approach

Please note that to obtain alignment on the `Timestamp` you need to set `base=20` in this particular situation (please refer to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html#pandas.Series.resample) for the rationale).

```
for name, df2 in df.groupby('Name'):
        df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.resample("40L", on='Timestamp2', base=20, convention='start').apply(lambda r: r.iloc[0]))
        df3 = df3.set_index('Timestamp')        
        print(name, df3.drop(columns=['Timestamp2']))
```

Resulting in:

```
          Name             Data
Timestamp                      
5.26        A1  [1.0, 1.2, 1.9]
5.30        A1  [1.2, 1.4, 0.9]
          Name             Data
Timestamp                      
5.26        A2  [1.0, 1.2, 1.9]
5.30        A2  [1.2, 1.4, 0.9]
```

---

### Selecting index sampling

A different approach that does not use `resample` but yields the same result (since you are not using the samples in-between the desired sample points):

```
for name, df2 in df.groupby('Name'):
    df2['Timestamp2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp'], unit='s')
    first = df2['Timestamp2'].iloc[0]
    selector = pd.date_range(start=first, freq='40L', periods=len(df2['Timestamp2']) / 2 + 1)
    df3 = df2[df2['Timestamp2'].isin(selector)]
    print(df3.drop(columns=['Timestamp2']))
```

Result:

```
  Name  Timestamp             Data
0   A1       5.26  [1.0, 1.2, 1.9]
2   A1       5.30  [1.2, 1.4, 0.9]
  Name  Timestamp             Data
4   A2       5.26  [1.0, 1.2, 1.9]
6   A2       5.30  [1.2, 1.4, 0.9]
```

Please note that I copied the data for `'A2'` `Name` label.

Comment: `df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[::2])` is a little better.

Comment: I need to work with `.resample()` or anything like that because i've other dataframes at different frequencies (e.g. from 80 to 50hz or from 200 to 50hz), just in this case is exaclty the half. 
As alghoritm of aggregation .mean() is a good solution.