# Plot e.g. max value of a month in time series data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have some time series data, where the data is in 15 min intervals for a year. What I would like to do is to find e.g. the max value for one month, or week. Is there some way/command to easily divide time series data into monthly/weekly intervals so it also accounts for skewed months, or do I need to do some manuel coding like taking from 01 to 30 (or something like that) to get the data for one month.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001389/pandas-resample-documentation) is also helpful.